# ViewModel in architect component - android

Tags: android, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I have a lot of `fragment` base `architect component`.
 Is this true that I create `ViewModel` for per `fragment`? or I should create one ViewModel for all `fragment`?

Comment: What is the task that you're trying to accomplish? Base your answer on that question, rather than just throw things at things. ViewModel is a tool.

Comment: In per view model class i call AppRepository base singlton and i have 12 class base viewmodel that i call in per class app repository base singleton. Is this true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Saw many project that uses ViewModel for each Activity, and they pass them to their fragments if needed.

Same goes for me, but figure out what functions that Activity will do, and then build a ViewModel based on that functions:

- Activity/Fragments that create an object.
- Activity/Fragment that fetch a list.
- Activity/Fragment that deal with Objects, like delete, update.

> You can pass ViewModel to fragments. Also you can use inheritance with your ViewModels.